Why were these things specifically instructed by God to be done by "the door" in Exodus 29?
There are several mentions of by "the door" in Exodus 29.

4 “And Aaron and his sons you shall bring to the door of the
tabernacle of meeting, and you shall wash them with water.


10 “You shall also have the bull brought before the tabernacle of
meeting, and Aaron and his sons shall put their hands on the head of
the bull. 11 Then you shall kill the bull before the Lord, by the
door of the tabernacle of meeting


31 “And you shall take the ram of the consecration and boil its flesh
in the holy place. 32 Then Aaron and his sons shall eat the flesh of
the ram, and the bread that is in the basket, by the door of the
tabernacle of meeting.


41 And the other lamb you shall offer at twilight; and you shall
offer with it the grain offering and the drink offering, as in the
morning, for a sweet aroma, an offering made by fire to the Lord. 42
This shall be a continual burnt offering throughout your generations
at the door of the tabernacle of meeting before the Lord, where I will
meet you to speak with you.

Based on these verse, this is my question:
Why were these things specifically instructed to be done by "the door"?
Is there a significance to these things being done by "the door"?
EXTRA:
Do any scholars see a connection to Jesus in these passages?

The relevant phrase that you're referring to as "by the door" is

פֶּ֖תַח אֹ֥הֶל מוֹעֵֽד

or "by the entrance of the appointed tent". Jewish tradition teaches that this phrase denotes a specific place in the Mishkan, the courtyard itself which is outside of the entrance:

See Rashi on Exodus:

פתח אהל מועד. בַּחֲצַר הַמִּשְׁכָּן שֶׁלִּפְנֵי הַפֶּתַח:


By the entrance of the appointed tent: in the court of the Mishkan which was in front of the entrance (my translation)


Thank you for your answer.

The activities described by the OP were directly tied to the setting of the tabernacles, as the Bronze Laver for washing and Bronze Altar for offerings were located at the entrance of the tabernacle. It's crucial to note that the term 'Tabernacle' refers to the tent of the Holy Place and Holy of Holies, it does not include the entire framework surrounding it. For detailed instruction on its construction, please refer to Exodus 26 where divine guidance is outlined.

As the Spirit had not been given at that time (John 7:39), the tabernacle symbolized God dwelt among His people who being rescued from slavery of Egypt (symbolize sin). Moreover, it served as a foreshadow to the ultimate salvation brought by Jesus Christ.
Hebrews 8:1-5 NIV

1 Now the main point of what we are saying is this: We do have such a high priest, who sat down at the right hand of the throne of the Majesty in heaven, 2 and who serves in the sanctuary, the true tabernacle set up by the Lord, not by a mere human being. 3 Every high priest is appointed to offer both gifts and sacrifices, and so it was necessary for this one also to have something to offer. 4 If he were on earth, he would not be a priest, for there are already priests who offer the gifts prescribed by the law. 5 They serve at a sanctuary that is a copy and shadow of what is in heaven. This is why Moses was warned when he was about to build the tabernacle: “See to it that you make everything according to the pattern shown you on the mountain.”

Hebrews 9:11-12 NIV

11 But when Christ came as high priest of the good things that are now already here, he went through the greater and more perfect tabernacle that is not made with human hands, that is to say, is not a part of this creation. 12 He did not enter by means of the blood of goats and calves; but he entered the Most Holy Place once for all by his own blood, thus obtaining eternal redemption.

The act of 'Washing' from the Bronze Laver represents Baptism - "He saved us through the washing of rebirth and renewal by the Holy Spirit" (Titus 3:5)
Offerings presented at the Bronze Altar represent repentance and the granting of forgiveness for sins. The sacrificial animals serve as a prefiguration of Christ's ultimate redemption - "he entered the Most Holy Place once for all by his own blood, thus obtaining eternal redemption." (Hebrews 9:12)
These rituals were to be conducted before the Tabernacle, signifying the divine witness.

Thank you for the very informative answer.

Almost everything about the ancient Israelite tabernacle represented Jesus somehow.  Indeed, the NT makes much of this:

Jesus was the fulfilment of what the sanctuary/temple typified, John 2:19-21, Heb 9:1-28, 10:1-18
Jesus represented the foundation of the temple as well, 1 Peter 2:4-8 (Compare Isa 28:16, Ps 118:22)
Jesus’ body was represented by the curtain in the temple, Heb 10:20.
Jesus was the bread of life, John 6:35, 41, 48 (compare Ex 25:23-30, Lev 24:8).
Jesus was the light of life, John 8:12, 9:5 (compare the lampstand Ex 25:31-39, Lev 24:3, 4, Isa 53:11, Ps 56:13, etc)
Jesus provides the water of life, John 4:13, 14 (Compare the laver Ex 30:17-21.  See also 1 Cor 6:11)
Jesus is the promised seed of the woman Gal 3:16 (compare Gen 3:15, and the Abrahamic Covenant)
Jesus was the Passover Lamb and thus the promised Messiah, John 1:29, 1 Cor 5:7, 1 Peter 1:19 (compare Ex 12:1-14).
Jesus is the High Priest of the New Covenant in fulfilment of the Levitical covenant, Heb 4:14-16, 5:10, 7:23-28, because He was “pure, blameless, set apart” exactly as the Levites were.  See also Heb 9:15, 12:24.
Jesus provided the blood of the new covenant of which the communion ceremony was to be a memorial, Matt 26:28, Mark 14:24, Luke 22:20, 1 Cor 11:25, Heb 13:20, 1 Peter 1:19 (compare Ex 24:5, 8).
Jesus was the anti-type of the “red heifer” (Num 19:1-10) and its associated ashes that “purify our consciences from works of death”, Heb 9:13, 14.

"Door/entrance"
In the tabernacle (which is only an English word for "tent", which it was), there were no "doors" but actually curtained entrances.  The word used in Ex 29:3, 11, 32, 42 is פֶתַח (pethach) = "opening, doorway, entrance" (Strong's).  In the ancient tabernacle, three such curtained entrances existed:

the curtain at the entrance to outer court acted as a door to the outer court
the curtain between the outer court and holy place was also a door
there was also a curtain between the holy place and the most holy place.

The "door" or curtain Ex 29 is the first of these and these references all describe the place, just inside the curtain to the outer court where sacrificial animals were slaughtered.  This explains the repeated reference to the "door"/"entrance".
My list above (ie, #3) states that Jesus' body represents the curtain to the tabernacle.  Jesus also references a few times that He was the "door" to the sheepfold, John 10:7-9.
All this symbolism appears to teach that Jesus was both the door to the heavenly tabernacle and also represented the sacrificial lamb which was offered for sin near the entrance.
Thus, Jesus is the only way to enter the heavenly sanctuary, via the blood of Jesus and the door/entrance of His crucified body.

Heb 10:19-21 - Therefore, brothers, since we have confidence to enter
the Most Holy Placed by the blood of Jesus, by the new and living way
opened for us through the curtain of His body, and since we have a
great priest over the house of God, 22let us draw near with a sincere
heart in full assurance of faith, having our hearts sprinkled to
cleanse us from a guilty conscience and our bodies washed with pure
water.
Heb 6:19, 20 - We have this hope as an anchor for the soul, firm and
secure. It enters the inner sanctuary behind the curtain, 20where
Jesus our forerunner has entered on our behalf. He has become a high
priest forever in the order of Melchizedek.


+1. I appreciate your attention to detailed answers. To clarify. Did all this occur out in the courtyard?

@Jason_ - yes - all sacrifice occurred in the courtyard.  Nothing was sacrificed in the holy places
